# Cannot see the file I have upload to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, putty, pscp

The pscp tell me, it is successful.

```
pscp -P 22 part-00003 username@172.31.143.131:/home/username/lab2_hdfs

username@172.31.143.131's password:
part-00000                | 758 kB | 758.9 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
```

But I didn't see it in my hadoop when I use hdfs dfs -ls, why?

Answer (score -1):

HDFS is not the same as your local filesystem. You can't upload files to HDFS using SCP